# How do I get date in a specific format into my HTML form from a cell into Google Spreadsheet with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, formatting

Good day to you.

https://www.bpwebs.com/pull-data-from-google-sheets-to-html-table/#more-21726

When data is being pulled to HTML / data array - how can we format the data?

Like Date in a specific format, Strings as Uppercase, numbers with 3 decimals etc.

Please can any one help.

Thanks in advance to the SO community.

regards
sA

Comment: Normally, date field of form is `type="date"` or `type="datetime-local"`. They have required format and the display cannot be changed. Could you be by specify what is your goal?

Comment: Also, it not confusing that whether you are working on Google Apps Script or HTML(js). Please provide your code.

Comment: using Google Apps Script to pull data from Google Sheets to HTML table using a data array. user is allowed to select a row and data is populated to the form.
I want the data to be formatted as dd-MM-yyyy instead of yyyy-MM-dd

My HTML form has the following 

<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="rtiDate" >RTI Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rtiDate" name="rtiDate"   onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" required>
</div>

This allows the user to input the date using a date picker.

Comment: So your question is how to format the date got from Spreadsheet?

Comment: yes.  during the population of data to array.

Comment: I am unable to edit my question so posted the function as a answer.

Also comment says the character limit  exceeds  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

```js
function ss2Form() {
  /* ... */

  /* use it if the display format in sheet is dd-MM-yyyy
  const dates = range.getDisplayValues();
 */

  const rawDates = range.getValues();
  const dates = rawDates.map(value => {
    return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(value[0]), 'Your Time Zone', 'dd-MM-yyyy');
  });
  return dates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function createTable(dataArray) {
        if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
          var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                       "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                         "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                          "<th scope='col'>ORDERNUMBER</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>QUANTITYORDERED</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>PRICEEACH</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>ORDERLINENUMBER</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>SALES</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>ORDERDATE</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>STATUS</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>QTR_ID</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>MONTH_ID</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>YEAR_ID</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>PRODUCTLINE</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>MSRP</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>PRODUCTCODE</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>CUSTOMERNAME</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>PHONE</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>ADDRESSLINE1</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>ADDRESSLINE2</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>CITY</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>STATE</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>POSTALCODE</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>COUNTRY</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>TERRITORY</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>CONTACTLASTNAME</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>CONTACTFIRSTNAME</th>"+
                          "<th scope='col'>DEALSIZE</th>"+
                        "</tr>"+
                      "</thead>";
          for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
              result += "<tr>";
              for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                  result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
              }
              result += "</tr>";
          }
          result += "</table>";
          var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
          div.innerHTML = result;
        }else{
          var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
          //div.empty()
          div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
        }
      }
```

store ORDERDATE in array as dd-MM-yyyy